# selecting from a list of results

Tags: powershell, select, get-wmiobject

I am retrieving the last logged on user using the script below - whilst I can get a list of the accounts, I only need to retrieve those that contain the "domain" name, and not accounts from the "local server name".

```
$Users = Get-WmiObject Win32_LoggedOnUser -ComputerName $ADComputer |
         Select Antecedent -Unique
```

```
\\.\root\cimv2:Win32_Account.Domain="LocalServer",Name="SYSTEM"
\\.\root\cimv2:Win32_Account.Domain="LocalServer",Name="NETWORK SERVICE"  
\\.\root\cimv2:Win32_Account.Domain="Domain",Name="user1"
```

So I am only expecting it to return

```
\\.\root\cimv2:Win32_Account.Domain="Domain",Name="user1"
```

I have tried the following:

```
$Users | Select $_.Antecedent | Where {$_.Antecedent.name -like "user1"}
```

But this returns blank. How can I select this line only? In addition,  I want to ultimately return "user1" in my results.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
  Get-WmiObject Win32_LoggedOnUser -ComputerName $ADComputer  | where { ($_.Antecedent -split "=")[2] -like "*user1*" } |  select @{N="Name";ex={($_.Antecedent -split "=")[2]}}
```

Comment: That's great, but it returns the result twice?

Comment: Because your Get-WmiObject commad return 2 entries ;) yes -unique is the solution or -first 1  :)  If its ok, click on the up arrow